Java - Identifying File System operations from ProcessBuilder/Process
I'm building and then running a process through ProcessBuilder as such:
final String cmd = myStringBuilder.toString();
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", cmd);
final Process process = processBuilder.start();

Here, process has a 50/50 chance of spawning a file somewhere on the local disk and writing to it - I'm looking to figure out where this file is being written to (ideally its absolute path on the disk). With Java, and without any modification to the program run by process, is there any way I can essentially "spy" on this process to retrieve the path of the file being written to? JNA with Windows API is acceptable to use here.

Who is entering the cmd text, in what way are they entering it, and what are the options and restrictions for the cmd text?   You have access to the cmd String, can't you analyze it with your code?

@HovercraftFullOfEels the cmd string is just a path to an executable on the local disk (fetched from our database), that will create and write to files on the local disk. it could be an exe file, a jar file, or a bat file. the cmd string contains no info on the output file the executable creates

Also, process I/O operations can be accessed by calling getInputStream, getErrorStream and getOutputStream on the Process. What happens when you access these and handle them?

@HovercraftFullOfEels getInputStream returns the output of System.out, echo etc. from the executable, and getErrorStream returns the same but for System.err. the Process itself doesn't seem to have any hooks into file system operations

I think that most of the ProcessBuilder internals must be in native code and therefore not interpreted by the JVM. I believe that this would prevent you from doing what you are asking about doing.

@HovercraftFullOfEels yeah, I was afraid of that. was trying to avoid using the filesystem WatchService but that may be the only good answer here. thanks for your time!
